# equal mixed partial derivatives satisfying Laplace equation

Tags: calculus

For question 1, part (b), I'm a little stuck:
[image]

I'm not certain about how equal mixed partial derivatives work. My attempt so far is:

$a_{xx}$ = $a_{yy}$ and $b_{xx}$ = $b_{yy}$, so

$a_{xx}$ + $b_{yy}$ = $a_{yy}$ + $b_{xx}$ - but by Cauchy-Riemann equations $b_{xx}$ = $-a_{yy}$

therefore, $a_{xx}$+$b_{yy}$ = $a_{yy}$-$a_{yy}$

or $a_{xx}$+$b_{yy}$ $= 0 = f_{xx}+f_{yy}$ as required to satisfy the Laplace equation. Is this okay or have I misunderstood the idea of equal partial derivatives

Answer (score 0):

Start by applying Laplace's equation to $\Delta(a+b)$, one obtains
$$
\Delta(a+b) = a_{xx}+a_{yy}+b_{xx}+b_{yy} 
$$
but since $a$ and $b$ satisfy C-R relations
$$
a_x = b_y\\
a_y = -b_x
$$
The above can be simplified
$$
\Delta(a+b) = (a_x)_x+(a_y)_y+(b_x)_x+(b_y)_y \\
=b_{yx}-b_{xy} - a_{yx}+a_{xy} = 0
$$
The last equality holds because the mixed partials commute